# Wrapping a div id OVER a div class (so the div class is inside) is that ok?

Tags: html

What i mean is this -

```
<div id="apples">
   <div class="oranges">
     some content
   </div> <!-- end of oranges div class -->
</div> <!-- end of apples div id -->
```

The reason i ask is because I have a CSS anchor effect that uses :target - with the effect being that it highlights the back of the div background - but that can only be triggered with a div ID - so, is it ok to wrap a div class in a div id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an `id` and `class` to the same `div`.

```
<div id="apples" class="oranges"></div>
```

Comment: Really! I must be slow on the uptake here......i just always thought that they were never to be mixed...

Ill test it out - thanks

Comment: yes. Often useful to assign general styles to the div and use the id to add specific styles.